# Toggle parent and children Datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a scenario where I need to place a wpf datagrid inside the rowDetails template of another datagrid.I have the toggle buttons on each row of parent datagrid to expand and collapse that row details template and I had a toggle button in the header column of parent datagrid to expand all the row details templates in one click.Can someone suggest the way to achieve the toggle functionality as explained using mvvm.

Thanks in advance

Comment: MVVM moves the logic flow outside the UI objects to put them in other more testable and flexible objects. Have you tried to put the Trigger Button logic outside the UI elements? What have you tried so far? Can you please share some of you code?

Comment: I cleared the issue bye adding a extra bool property in the object which i am binding to the datagrid to get toggle functionality. Thanks for your response.